# CSS - word-spacing not working when doing absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, position, word-spacing

I have a div and some spans inside it. I have a problem that when I use absolute positioning my `word-spacing` property does not work properly.

For more clearance [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/tfdxt/) is the jsFiddle.

**HTML:**

```
<section id="header">
    <span>HOME</span>
    <span class="no-spacing">ABOUT US</span>
    <span>PORTFOLIO</span>
    <span class="no-spacing">CONTACT US</span>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    background-image: url(http://www.7daysinhavana.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/7days/images/commun/back_header_global.jpg);
    font-family: 'GarageGothicBlackRegular';
    word-spacing: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#header span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.no-spacing {
    word-spacing: 0px;
}
```

How can I fix that error?

**Any help would be highly appreciated!**

Comment: What did you expect to see? I see expected result in chrome.

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tfdxt/1/?

Comment: @raam86 I expect to see those span separated by 10px after each word.

Comment: @j08691 exactly, if that would be an answer, I would have accepted it!

Comment: Word-spacing seems like a round-about way of applying padding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your spans in a div (or other container) and position the container like:

```
<section id="header">
    <div>
        <span>HOME</span>
        <span class="no-spacing">ABOUT US</span>
        <span>PORTFOLIO</span>
        <span class="no-spacing">CONTACT US</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#header div {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tfdxt/1/)**